# xcodebuild code sign error provisioning profile even though all profiles are in correct folder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a build server that checks out my xcode projects but there are a couple of issues. I need to build the app if the checkout occurs, but I'm not commiting the .xcworkspace file since more than one person works on the project.

I'm running the following code in my terminal from the project's directory:

```
sudo xcodebuild -configuration Debug
```

It eventually fails with the error:

```
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '7DXXX-XXXX-XXXX....' can't be found
```

I opened my directory at:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\Profiles/
```

The profile is definitely there, the certificate is correct, and my debug build does not code sign.

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: I would verify the actual profile. The number may have changed. Does that number match exactly the newest provisioning profile?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I've checked the name of the profile and the values match completely. I even tried the following parameter (3 variations):

PROVISIONING_PROFILE='profilename.mobileprovision'
PROVISIONING_PROFILE='profilename'
PROVISIONING_PROFILE='~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/profilename.mobileprovision'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for provision profile id in the profilename.mobileprovision file. Open the file and search for UUID to find this, it will be in XXX-XXX-XXXX format. Pass this as the value of PROVISIONING_PROFILE in xcodebuild command

```
sudo xcodebuild -configuration Debug PROVISIONING_PROFILE=<Provisioning Profile Id>
```

Comment: In the comment above you mentioned the three variations that you have tried. Just want to make sure that you tried with the UUID of the profile. It has been working for me from last few months.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that and it still didn't work. I ended up just calling xcodebuild -configuration Debug -target $TARGET_NAME in my script without calling any profile and it seems to work. I guess whichever developer works on the project just needs to make sure they commit the correct provisioning profiles so that it'll work for my CI server.

Comment: make the .p12 file into the keychain 'system' not the 'login'. I dragged it,and it worked! Good luck.

Comment: BTW To get the ID from the file you can use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print UUID' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i ${WORKSPACE}/FILE.mobileprovision)`

Answer (score 1):

if you have the correct certificate,and have imported it.
do : sudo xcodebuild -configuration Debug PROVISIONING_PROFILE=""

Answer (score 0):

It's because you run as **root**. The provisioning profile is installed for your specific user....